# Opening PDF in Controller- Can't use open parameters

Tags: java, spring, pdf, adobe

In my controller I want to open a pdf and stream it to the browser.  This code works fine if I don't use the open parameters.  However, I need to use an open parameter like #search="java" after the filename.  Using open parameters works fine if it is a url but is there a way that I can use adobe open parameters to open the file.

Code that I am using is:

```
private static final String DOCUMENT_LOCATION = "C:\\testPDF\\mytest.pdf#search=" + "\"" + "java" + "\"";


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

    // set some response headers 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(DOCUMENT_LOCATION); 
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 

    // Copy the bits from instream to outstream 
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
    int len; 
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) { 
        out.write(buf, 0, len); 
    } 
    in.close(); 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, you need a "search parameter after the filename"? You're specifying a file name for Java to open. You can only give it the filename, not random parameters that have nothing to do with the filesystem.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, I can open the file but I don't think this is the way that I need to open the file.  Is there a way I can open a file on a local directory and still use the open parameters?

Comment: Not sure how... One thing you could try is checking the response headers when you open it via URL to see if something is getting sent back that causes the browser/reader to do the search.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm guessing it's actually the Adobe Reader plugin that inspects the client-side URL for that parameter, so there's nothing special to send back.

Comment: @Inerdia That'd be my guess too, but I'd still look, 'cuz I'm ornery like that. If the URL contained the parameter, I'm not sure how Reader would know it wasn't an actual file, though. Or in the attachment's filename? Dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it turns out that adobe no longer supports open parameters, so what I ended up doing was passing the search url parameter which opens the search function in Adobe automatically.  Unfortunatley this does not work in Firefox only in IE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use certain parameters supported by Adobe Acrobat Reader then you would have to search for a way to specify those parameters to a plugin in the browser or to the reader in the client machine.

There is no way to "open" the file in the server taking those parameters into account since Java is just opening a file and knows nothing about its format.

Comment: That's not really an answer; kind of just a rehash of the comments.

Comment: @Dave Newton: may the comments should have be posted as answers. Because a simple "this is not possible" or is always a valid answer.

Comment: well maybe I should change my tactic.  I know open parameters works properly if I use an url.  In my project I could include a pdf directory that holds the pdfs and call it like I would a jsp.  Only issue is that the pdfs can go stale and I would have to get updates to them.  I can have a scheduled task to go pick up the lastest pdfs, but where should I put the updated files?  Should I create a new thread?

Comment: to be honest my true underlying problem is that I want to hightlight the pdfs when a search word is found, but it seems based on my research that Adobe does not support highlighting anymore and the best way is to pass a search parameter?